# How can I have another Angular 4 app on a child URL?

Tags: angular

I have setup an Angular 4 app on root "/". I would like to setup another Angular 4 app on child URL like "/admin" with its own index.html and routing. How can I achieve this? What changes I need to do to the project file .angular-cli.json so that the second angular runs from child URL?

Comment: I dont want to use routing to /admin. I want two independent Angular 4 apps one at "/" and another at "/admin"

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Configure your webserver to serve different application based on the url

Comment: Shouldn't you simply use lazy module loading?

Comment: Isn't it easier to create another NgModule and have two independent SPAs which can be switch by router.